# setcookie() not working from login form

Tags: php, cookies

Cookies are not set.  The setcookie() structure looks right to me, but for some reason I can't get it to work.  Here is the form I am using:

```
if(isset($_POST['LoginBtn']))
{

$username = mysql_escape_string($_POST['username']);
$password = mysql_escape_string($_POST['password']);
if($_POST['remember_me']==1){

                $twoDays = 60 * 60 * 24 * 300 + time();
                setcookie('UserLogin', $username, $twoDays);
                setcookie('UserPass', $password, $twoDays);
            }
        echo '<script>window.location="index.php"</script>';


}
?>

<html>
<head>
<title>Log In</title>
</head>
<body>
<form  method="post" action="login2.php">
<input type="text"  name="username"  value="<?php echo $_COOKIE['UserLogin'];?>"  />
<input type="password"  name="password"  value="<?php echo $_COOKIE['UserPass'];?>"  />
<input type="checkbox" name="remember_me" value="1"/> Remember Me
<input type="hidden" name="LoginBtn" value="1" />
<button type="submit">Login Now</button>
</form>
```

And here is the index page where I am attempting to echo the cookies:

```
<?php
 echo "<br />cookie user_name: ".$_COOKIE['UserLogin']; 
  echo "<br />cookie user_pass: ".$_COOKIE['UserPass']; 
 echo "<br /><a href='login2.php'>Back</a>";
?>
```

Comment: Have you checked in browser whether cookie is generated or not?

Comment: Don't use `mysql_` functions. They won't work in current PHP versions. It's only used in stone-age PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Just a small change

`$twoDays = 60 * 60 * 24 * 30 + time();`

Comment: This solution does not set a cookie either, but does not throw an error like the answer below.  Perhaps that is a clue

Answer (score 0):

Use time to something similer to this

```
$twoDay = time() + (86400 * 30), "/"); // 86400 = 1 day
```

Your cookie not setting because of wrong expire time

Comment: This solution causes the following error:  Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned above, I was getting a 500 error when I set the cookie time incorrectly, and that was even before submitting the form.  So I changed the form action to a separate page (login_ac.php) and it worked.

//Form Action:

```
<?php
$username = mysql_escape_string($_POST['username']);
$password = mysql_escape_string($_POST['password']);
if($_POST['remember_me']==1){
                $twoDays = 60 * 60 * 24 * 30 + time();
                setcookie('UserLogin', $username, $twoDays);
                setcookie('UserPass', $password, $twoDays);
            }
        echo '<script>window.location="index.php"</script>';
        ?>
```